# Do android os run javascript bundler for native components for react native app

Tags: android, react-native

I install my react native app (signed apk) on new android device. It stuck on splash screen. I tried to uninstall and reinstall but still stuck on splash screen. This is the behaviour on almost all android devices. If I clear storage and cache then its work. so anyone who will install the will have to clear the cache and storage to run the app which is not user friendly because not every user know this. does react native app run javascript bundler when first time app installed on device or anything else going on here. what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you are building Signed APK using Android Studio. Then React native does not needs bundler to be started. Your issue is related to Local storage. Can you please clarify, if you are using LocalStorage in your application code.

There is one more way to track the APK error. Connect through USB and open Android studio and goto Run tab, to check the error while running the APK.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
yes I'm using react-native-secure-storage. if its issue in storage how can I track it?

This is the logs I got after installing the app and its stuck on splash screen.
please check the logs here: https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/505w